# Dividing just by subtracting and finding the remainder- without using the division operator

Tags: java

I seem have been able to figure out the first par at with the multiplication but my logic is a tad confused when trying to figure out the remainder. When i run it i just get a negative number instead of it looking like division- any help will be greatly appreciated!

***Main Java Class***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment4 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int multiplicand, multiplier;
    int dividend, divisor;
    int total=0, total2 = 0, countMult, countDiv;

    System.out.print("Enter a multiplican: ");
    multiplicand = inputReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a multiplier: ");
    multiplier = inputReader.nextInt();

    countMult = multiplier;
    while(multiplier > 0) {

        total = total + multiplicand;
        multiplier--;
    }

    System.out.println(multiplicand + " times " + countMult + " equals " + total );

    System.out.print("Enter a dividend: ");
    dividend = inputReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a divisor: ");
    divisor = inputReader.nextInt();

    countDiv = divisor;
    while(divisor > 0) {

        total2 = total2 - dividend;
        divisor--;
    }

    System.out.print(dividend + " divided by " + countDiv + " equals " + total2 );


}

}
```

Comment: How about `while (total2 > divisor)`...

Comment: If you had the right answer in the total2 variable, would that while() loop "know"?   What would happen if you subtracted dividend from the correct answer?

Comment: Have you learned how to write a method? This seems like a good opportunity to do so if you have.

Comment: i'm not able to use methods. Has to all be hard-coded :/ and i replaced the while(divisor > 0) with while (total2 > divisor) and when i ran it i got "0"

Comment: You do division in binary exactly the same way you were (I hope) taught to do long division in school, except you're doing it in binary instead of decimal, so the only "estimate" you have to make for the next step is choosing whether to use the divisor x0 or x1.  There is a "non-restoring" division algorithm that's a hair faster (in theory), but you need to tackle the basic one first.

Comment: (And, as you will recall from your long division, shifting is involved.)

Comment: (And if you turn in that multiply you're going to get a D- on it at best.  You should be shifting there too.  You do it the same way you learned to do decimal multiplication, only in binary.)

Comment: The "duplicate" is nowhere near being a duplicate -- it's finding a remainder, not doing division.  There might be a valid dupe somewhere, but that's not it.

Comment: How should my code look using the variables i have in my code though :/?

Comment: To multiply you should test one digit at a time of the multiplier while shifting the multiplicand one digit each cycle -- just as you'd do in decimal arithmetic.